I'm getting an error installing node-speaker on Mac
I'm getting the following error log when trying to install speaker.
$ npm install speaker
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/username/code/play/node_modules/speaker
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/Users/username/code/play/node_modules/speaker/build'
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/output/deps/mpg123/src/output/coreaudio.o
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/Users/username/code/play/node_modules/speaker/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.12.2 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.4 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/bin/python3.12"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/bin/python3.12
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/nix/store/ridvrr7dsnxpvh3f1sr41xiwvwk1nnkg-nodejs-20.12.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/Users/username/code/play/node_modules/speaker/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/nix/store/ridvrr7dsnxpvh3f1sr41xiwvwk1nnkg-nodejs-20.12.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/Users/username/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.12.2/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/username/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.12.2',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/nix/store/ridvrr7dsnxpvh3f1sr41xiwvwk1nnkg-nodejs-20.12.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/username/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.12.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/username/code/play/node_modules/speaker',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! ../deps/mpg123/src/output/coreaudio.c:14:10: fatal error: 'AudioUnit/AudioComponent.h' file not found
npm ERR! #include <AudioUnit/AudioComponent.h>
npm ERR!          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [deps/mpg123/output.target.mk:139: Release/obj.target/output/deps/mpg123/src/output/coreaudio.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/nix/store/ridvrr7dsnxpvh3f1sr41xiwvwk1nnkg-nodejs-20.12.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:209:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/nix/store/ridvrr7dsnxpvh3f1sr41xiwvwk1nnkg-nodejs-20.12.2/bin/node" "/nix/store/ridvrr7dsnxpvh3f1sr41xiwvwk1nnkg-nodejs-20.12.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/username/code/play/node_modules/speaker
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.12.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2024-07-19T17_26_24_870Z-debug-0.log

it's weird that #include <AudioUnit/AudioComponent.h> isn't being detected. I installed Xcode in case this required additional audio SDKs but it still doesn't work. Any idea how to make it build? thanks!
